# Launching Tensorboard: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow

I am unable to run tensorboard, and get the message:

```
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Installed TF on Ubuntu, using a virtenv, and pip as per instructions [install instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)
2. Confirmed TF was correctly installed by running the mnist example. Output was as expected
3. Attempted to run tensorboard using:

   ```
   tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/mnist_with_summaries/
   ```

Checked that this location does contain the summary files within the "test" and "train" directories

4. Command and error:

   ```
   (tensorflow_1_4_0) js@pchome01:~$ tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/mnist_with_summaries/
   bash: /home/js/tensorflow_1_4_0/bin/tensorboard: /home/js/tensorflow_1_3/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
   ```

In my virtenv folder for tensorflow_1_4_0, a tensorboard script exists:

```
#!/home/js/tensorflow_1_3/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from tensorboard.main import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

When I run the following from the terminal, no errors are reported:

```
from tensorboard.main import main
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Just spotted my silly mistake and posting the resolution in case others encounter this.

The meaning of the error message is that the interpreter of the code (in this case python3) cannot be found.
The first line of the tensorboard script:

```
#!/home/js/tensorflow_1_3/bin/python3
```

This tells the compiler to look for python3 at this location, however this path is incorrect and the virtual environment is actually called tensorflow_1_4_0.
Therefore changing this line to the following fixed the error:

```
#!/home/js/tensorflow_1_4_0/bin/python3
```